# Why the process started by a bash script will not exit after the terminal has been closed?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, tty

#### Case 1:

I execute `sleep 1000 &` in gnome-terminal and then close the terminal. The `sleep` process does not exist.

#### Case 2:

Here's a script `t.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 1000 &
```

I execute `./t.sh` in gnome-terminal and then close the terminal. The `sleep` process exists (known by `ps aux`). Should not the process be closed?

Comment: Question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Cyrus I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Jürgen Hötzel says in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649000/900078) is true but that's not exactly what's happening.

#### Case 1:

When the `gnome-terminal` is closed, the tty (including pty) driver would get a *disconnect* event of the tty and send `SIGHUP` to the *controlling process* associated with the tty. Here the *controlling process* is bash and bash will receive the `SIGHUP`. Then, according to the [bash manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> - The  shell  exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`.  Before exiting, an *interactive shell* resends the `SIGHUP` to all jobs, running or stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the `SIGHUP`.
> - If the `huponexit` shell option has been set with `shopt`, bash sends a `SIGHUP` to all jobs when an *interactive login shell* exits.

So for Case 1, bash will resend `SIGHUP` to the background job `sleep` which will be killed by the signal (this is the default behavior of `SIGHUP`).

(The `huponexit` option mentioned by Jürgen Hötzel only affects *interactive login shells* which exit *voluntarily*. But for Case 1, the bash is killed by `SIGHUP`. And, the **[bash running in gnome-terminal is not necessarily a *login shell*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced/40313#40313)** though it's really an *interactive shell*.)

#### Case 2:

Here there are 2 bash processes involved:

- bash#1: The bash process which is running in the gnome-terminal.
- bash#2: The bash process which runs the `t.sh` script.

When `t.sh` (bash#2) is running, `sleep 1000 &` starts as a background job of bash#2. After `t.sh` (bash#2) exits, the `sleep` will continue running but it'll become an orphan process and the `init` process will take care of it and `sleep`'s PPID will become 1 (PID of the `init` process).

When the gnome-terminal is closed, bash#1 will receive `SIGHUP` and bash#1 will resend `SIGHUP` to all it's jobs. But the `sleep` is not a job of bash#1 so `sleep` will not receive the `SIGHUP` so it'll continue running after bash#1 completes.

Comment: Hi whjm, thank you for your help. I am sorry that I posted this duplicate question, and I should delete this one because this question is better on [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). So would you mind remove your valuable answer to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385639/why-the-process-started-by-a-bash-script-will-not-exit-after-the-terminal-has-be/385653?noredirect=1#comment686731_385653)?

Comment: Regarding https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385653/29039 , I just tried both `gnome-terminal` and `putty` and confirmed that closing the window would send `SIGHUP` to the Bash running in it. This is at least the *default* behavior though I'm not sure if there's a way to change the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

When using an interactive login shell, bash will send a *HUP* signal to your jobs on exit if this option is set:

```
juergen@samson:~ → shopt huponexit
huponexit       on
```

The default handler will terminate your process. When starting a *non-interactive* bash (like your script) the *huponexit* option is effectless. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: this does not really explain what's happening. please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In simple words, no. With "&" your are making the current process to run as background process. And you must kill it explicitly, according to my knowledge.